# What does Earthworm Jim's space suit possess?

Tags: video-games, cartoon, earthworm-jim

From the [game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm_Jim_(series)) and [cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm_Jim_(TV_series)) series, we see Earthworm Jim in his ultra-high-tech-indestructible-super-space-cyber-suit (or [super suit](http://earthwormjim.wikia.com/wiki/Super_suit) for short). From the wiki link, it is mentioned that:

> The suit has several high technological functions and gadgets, including a red Plasma Blaster for offense, and a Pocket Rocket for interplanetary travel.

**Along with the suit's artificial intelligence, what else does it possess?**

[image: D'oh!]

Comment: It also has a backpack, slightly visible in your picture, which Snott lives in during [EJ2](http://earthwormjim.wikia.com/wiki/Earthworm_Jim_2). And, apparently it contains boxers.

Comment: https://new.vk.com/doc-686436_186980476?dl=244b5f88fb2e8cb010

Comment: @Dpeif, oh yeah, forgot about him thx.

Comment: @Valorum, thanks for the link but will need to check it when i get back home (using phone atm).

Comment: @Valorum, I am struggling to access the link. It's taking forever to download even 10MB and eventually stops. If there is relevant info in the pdf file, maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @user35594 - This seems to load a bit quicker; http://gameadvanceplaythroughs.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/5/8/11580409/_earthworm_jim_instruction_manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the question, the suit has the [built-in AI, the blaster, and the Pocket Rocket](https://earthwormjim.fandom.com/wiki/Super_suit). There is also [Snott](https://earthwormjim.fandom.com/wiki/Snott), though he is not a part of the suit and comes from a different origin, which is not well established.

Then there's the backpack. It appears in many instances, while not being present in many other instances. It can be assumed to be part of the suit, though why it isn't found in all artwork presents a question.

The suit grants multiple benefits, from super speed and strength to incredible durability (though not indestructible, despite the suit's description). Jim controls it telekinetically, an ability granted to him by the suit. He was forcibly evolved by the suit "[at light speed](http://gameadvanceplaythroughs.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/5/8/11580409/_earthworm_jim_instruction_manual.pdf)" upon contact with it, necessitating several abilities for the suit: scanning things within it, altering them at a fundamental level, and doing both of these at incredible speeds.

The suit has a power source, either atom balls or the battery of the gods (from the games and cartoon, respectively).

The suit can have multiple temporary upgrades, from energy shields to enhancements to the blaster.

There are multiple gags involved that are probably just that, gags, and not accurate descriptions of items, such as the suit being filled with bran oats, and the boxers. Of course, in a series like this, perhaps taking anything seriously is the wrong approach, and the gags could very well be intended as actual components. Let the reader decide here.